# PHPを利用したHTTP_RANGEによる動画再生での現象

Tags: php, iphone

現在、cakephp 2.xを利用して動画の閲覧サイトを構築しております。
html側はvideoタグに動画ファイル(mp4形式)を直書きするのではなく、該当するidのphpスクリプトを記述しております。
php側はHTTP_RANGEを利用するコードにしており、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924061/using-php-to-output-an-mp4-video
を参考に実装しています。
しかし、特定の条件で動作不良が発生しており、原因の究明・対策が滞っており、皆様のお知恵をお借りできないかと思い投稿いたしました。

現象としては、当方のテスト環境のサーバーで動作させた場合は、どの条件でも問題なく動画再生ができるのですが、公開予定の別のサーバーでは、iphone(iOS10)、ipadのみ再生が出来ません。(PCの主なブラウザ、アンドロイド端末のブラウザでは再生可能です。）
パケットキャプチャなどで調査をしたいのですが、当方マックを持っていないので、厳しい状況です。

何かヒントになるような事でも結構ですので、ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: HTTP(S)通信であれば、Fiddlerなどのデバッグプロキシを使ってみるのはどうでしょうか。 http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS

Comment: ありがとうござます。早速試してみたいと思います。